# C++: What do these bitwise AND's and following comparisons do?

Tags: c++, algorithm, median

I'm currently going through this implementation of finding a median using two heaps:
[No. 30 - Median in Stream](http://codercareer.blogspot.com/2012/01/no-30-median-in-stream.html)

I understand the general basic algorithm, but I'm not sure how this exact implementation works. Specifically, I'm absolutely confused what these two lines do:

```
if(((minHeap.size() + maxHeap.size()) & 1) == 0)
....
if(size & 1 == 1)
```

I believe I understand the bitwise AND- it takes the two numbers and outputs a number in binary. With the comparison of == 0 or == 1, it would check literally if the bitwise AND comes out with a 0 or a 1, respectively. However, in the context of finding the median, what does this exactly do? I know it's important for keeping the heaps "even" (and keeping the median in between the two heaps), but other than that I'm not entirely sure. Is this really just a way to check if the sizes are different?

Comment: `x&1` is the same as `x%2`, it checks whether x is even or odd.

Comment: `x & (n - 1) = x % n` where `n` is a power of two.

Comment: It could be checking if either it's even/odd or equal/disequal to zero.

Comment: In terms of binary, how does that work out? (Thanks for all the responses!)

Comment: @tux3 - yes, but remember to not use this trick with signed integers, the logic inverts on negative numbers because of "two's compliment"

Comment: @iwolf: In what way is the logic inverted for negative numbers? For instance, in 2's complement, `-7 & 1` is `1`. And `-7 % 2` is non-zero.

Comment: @TonyK - oh my god, I just realized the logic doesn't invert on two's compliment negative numbers. Turns out I've been confused for a long time after getting wrongly called out for using this trick in an interview 3 or 4 years ago. The logic only inverts if using one's compliment... but yes, still totally agree about sticking to modulo for clarity.

Comment: @MDragon00: Never use `if(size & 1 == 1)`! It means `if(size & (1 == 1))`. Which, admittedly comes to the same thing in this case; but only by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the first test is true if lowest bit is zero, i.e. sum is even number. The second test is true if *size* is odd number (i.e. LSB is set).

Comment: So the comparison only checks the least significant bit, or am I still missing something here?

Comment: *&* is bitwise AND operation with 0x0000001 as right operand, i.e. only one LSB bit of left operand is important.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I kept thinking that it was doing a binary AND between the two sizes. Your clarification helped a ton.